# java Catch Exception root cause type

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I can catch the thrown exception with:

```
Throwable temp = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);
```

When I debug that, I see the type of that throwable, how can I get that information as a string? I can catch the exact message why exception occurred, but how about its type ?

Comment: What is ExceptionUtils?

Comment: temp.getClass().getName()?

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;

Comment: temp.getClass() returns me name "javax.naming.AuthenticationException" but actually "AuthenticationException" is only thing I want to accomplish :)

Comment: its not the message I want, its the type of the exception. The message I know how to catch, but want to get its type (in above example its "AuthenticationException"

Comment: temp.getClass().getSimpleName() then. You relly need to learn reading javadoc.

Comment: use temp.getClass().getSimpleName()

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question with code user **csn** given in comments. The next code gives you the exact name of the thrown exception:

```
ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e).getClass().getSimpleName()
```